# Wiring double pole thermostat when I only have 1 wire from the heater

Tags: electrical

I’ve got a set of wires coming from the panel (white, black, copper), and only one wire goes to the heater. I have a double thermostat. I connected L1 to the black from the panel and L2 to the white from the panel. Then I connected T1 to the lone wire that goes to the thermostat. What do I do with T2 (red)?

- Thermostat: Honeywell Home CT410B Manual 4 Wire Premium Baseboard/Line Volt Thermostat CT410B1017
- Heater: KING PAW2422-W PAW Pic-A-Watt Electric Wall Heater, 2250W / 240V

[image: my wiring of a double pole thermostat to a wall heater]

Comment: You can see how the previous thermostat was wired here: https://photos.app.goo.gl/z9pJ5WFPeyfFYuUy5

Comment: Heater: KING PAW2422-W PAW Pic-A-Watt Electric Wall Heater, 2250W / 240V, White

Comment: Thermostat: Honeywell Home CT410B Manual 4 Wire Premium Baseboard/Line Volt Thermostat CT410B1017

Comment: Please be sure to [edit] your question to include critical info like brand/model numbers. Not everyone reads comments and they can get deleted. I've done so for you in this case.

Answer (score 3):

The prior work was a hatchet job.  It will need to be repaired because it's improper and unsafe, as it is.

It looks like either the original black wire in the left cable broke off deep inside the box - but noting the ground wire is also destroyed, it's more likely the ass-hat who wired this just cut the wires off, because they think that's an appropriate solution to wires they don't know what to do with.  /facepalm how unnecessary.  But regardless, they obviously ran a second cable to the heater from another source, and are somehow using that.   Can we save it? Maybe.

The simplest answer is rewire the whole shebang but for the sake of the drywall, I would advise carefully surveying which wires are available, both at the thermostat and the heater.  Are you entirely sure that the intact black/white pair is from the supply?  (if so that's unfortunate.)

Can you get us some pix of the wires at the heater?  The only thing that makes sense is they *also* ran power to the *heater*...

If power indeed goes to the heater, I wouldn't be afraid to re-task the white and damaged black wire for a 24-volt thermostat circuit.  which would give us a chance to rearrange this thing to be 24 volts, by adding a transformer-relay such as a Honeywell Aube - assuming an audible click is tolerable.  If the guy didn't snip off the wires we need.

Comment: Here’s the heater. Thanks in advance. Apologies for my terribly long-winded video: https://photos.app.goo.gl/EMjYQwhnL1Drj4RN8

Comment: @David OK I see 3 complete **cables** (several wires wrapped in a sheath), and it looks like 1 from supply, 1 onward to another heater, and the one on the right is definitely a "Switch Loop" to your thermostat for this heater.  So it looks to me like you got lucky, and the intact /2 cable is your switch loop line.  You can wire a 1-pole thermostat, or a 2-pole thermostat with both elements in series. You won't use the odd white wire.

Comment: @DavidScoville please edit your original question to include these additional photos. By dragging them (or clicking the "sun & mountain" icon above the edit box) they'll be hosed by SE's image host and will make this a useful question for others in the future, long after you've deleted these from your Google drive to clear up space.

Comment: Agreed, we really dislike the "See my pictures <broken pictures follow>" thing, it hurts the quality of the forum.